# Facebook Comment Box disappear when using it with Backbone.js

Tags: facebook-graph-api, backbone.js, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I am trying to embedded Facebook comment boxes dynamically generated by Backbone.js in my HTML I have the following code right after the body in my HTML file.

```
<script>
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=147738045314917";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Then I dynamically generate the div tags using Backbone template. I embed the following html tag.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://something.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

The problem is that the comment box don't always show for some reason. I am also using the Facebook SDK in this page too.

I don't really get this, any help would be great. Thank a lot!

Comment: The javascript Facebook SDK is asynchronous isn't it? If so, it could be a loading order issue. That would explain why sometimes it works (Facebook loads before Backbone and is ready to go,) and sometimes it doesn't (Facebook is not ready.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding new `XFBML` elements to the DOM (or the HTML5 equivalent in this case), you want to call `FB.XFBML.parse` on the containing element in order to transform these.